# Присваивание значения полю

Tags: c, массивы, struct

В чём ошибка, почему нельзя так присваивать?

```
struct profile{
    char surname [255];
};

int main() {
    struct profile peoples [5];
    peoples[0].surname = {"Чаадаев"};
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в C фигурные скобки используются для инициализации.

```
struct profile peoples [5] = {"Чаадаев"};
```

Вот так можно, но это - инициализация только `peoples[0]`, остальные будут инициализированы нулями.

Comment: А как все инциализировать по строкам в виде : peoples[0].surname="qw"; peoples[1].surname="er"; peoples[2].surname="ty"... ?

Comment: `struct profile peoples [5] = {"Чаадаев","Пушкин","Толстой","Пупкин", "Вася"};` - примерно так.